# Can one get parameter values used in a method from within an ActionFilter?

Tags: c#, parameters, action-filter

Assume I have a controller method like this:

```
[Audit]
public JsonNetResult List(int start, int limit, string sort, string dir, string searchValue, SecurityInputModel securityData)
{
    ...
}
```

and an attribute defined as such:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        // auditing code here

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);

    } 
}
```

can I get at the value of start/limit/sort/etc from inside OnActionExecuted()?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can get the parameter values in `OnActionExecuting` using the [ActionExecutingContext.ActionParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext.actionparameters.aspx) property.

For example, the following test attribute writes the parameter names and values out to the response (the `ItemModel` class overrides `ToString` to just output its 2 properties):

```
public class CustomActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        response.Write(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
        response.Write("<br/>");

        foreach (var parameter in filterContext.ActionParameters)
        {
            response.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}", parameter.Key, parameter.Value));
        }
    }
}

[CustomActionFilter]
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Test(ItemModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

[image]

Comment: This only works for parameters set up in the MVC Routes, right?
Arbitrary URL Parameters won't pass through?

Comment: @Mir ...Thats true. But you can have all info in the Request object part of the ActionContext.